# Javascript - Fade image in?

Tags: javascript, css, fadein

Hello I have a button and when hovered over it will change the background-image of a div (I have more than one button that does the same to the same div)
instead of the images suddenly coming on the screen when hovering over the buttons I would like for them to fade in 
Could someone point me in the right path please without jQuery

Here is my code:

```
    function link01() {
document.getElementById("hover-change").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/1.jpg)";
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a fadeIn effect this might help you. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can `transition` background image in CSS

```
transition: background-image 1s linear
```

This is supported across most browsers (I think its in the process of being rolled out to Firefox/not sure about IE).

Appending different classes to the "hover-change" element depending on which element is hovered allows you to apply different images.